# How can I combine two queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to combine these queries:

```
UPDATE T1
SET Opening_date = T2.Opening_date
FROM FactTransaction T1
INNER JOIN DimStore T2 ON T1.cod_Store = T2.Cod_StoreKey
```

and

```
UPDATE FactTransaction
SET ORDINAL = DATEDIFF(DAY, Opening_Date, DATE)
```

In order to avoid insert the field `Opening_date` in my fact table. I don't know how to do it just with a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE T1 SET 
Opening_date = T2.Opening_date, 
ORDINAL = DATEDIFF(DAY, T2.Opening_Date, T1.DATE) 
FROM FactTransaction T1 
INNER JOIN DimStore T2 ON T1.cod_Store = T2.Cod_StoreKey;
```

...if I understand you correctly.

Edit: Ok, just go with:

```
UPDATE T1 SET 
ORDINAL = DATEDIFF(DAY, T2.Opening_Date, T1.DATE) 
FROM FactTransaction T1 
INNER JOIN DimStore T2 ON T1.cod_Store = T2.Cod_StoreKey;
```

Comment: yeah, the thing is that my fact table does not have the field "opening_date" which is on DimStore. So I want to get the datediff between Date (Factable) and Opening_date (DimStore)

Comment: Edited... Try that.